# Test size with small dataset with class imbalance

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, unbalanced-classes

what would a good split train/test be, having a class imbalance problem in the dataset and a small number of observations (<5000 obs)? Would it make sense to consider k-fold cross validation (e.g. 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If training is not too expensive, cross validation with as much folds as possible (even leave-one-out) is better. Because, let's say you have only 1% of the minority class, i.e. ~50 samples in your case, a single train/test split (like 80/20) might mean only 10 minority samples, which could increase the variance of your evaluation metrics.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, gunes. What about considering a k-fold = 5 instead of 10? The imbalance ratio is 90:10. I was considering 80/20 with oversampling techniques on training set

Comment: Practically, 90:10 in 5K samples is not too bad, and k=5 fold seems well enough. Note that this always depends on the specific data. As I mentioned, more folds is typically better but for each problem you get diminishing returns after some k. Oversampling is fine unless you apply it to test set.

Comment: thanks a lot, gunes. One more question: in case of 90:10, would it be ok to consider a train/test split of 80/20 or it would be too much?

Comment: It seems ok in case of 5K samples

Comment: thanks. Can you explain me how to understand if it is ok? I am asking because probably I would have said 70/30. For example, if it was between 3000 and 4000, would it be still ok?

Comment: It's just out of experience. I'm afraid I can't provide you with a formula to achieve "ok"ness :) Together with the complexity of the problem, it heavily depends on the algorithm used as well. With 5K samples, and a large deep neural net, it wouldn't probably be ok, too. But, with a decently complex algorithm, a 90:10 imbalance means 500 minority samples and 400 of them will be in your training set, which could be representative enough for some sets of problems to some extent, e.g. iris dataset. You should try and find out the sweet spot of your data, but as a starting point, it feels ok.